# Check Server Load of Another Server

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, operating-system

I have 2 servers on one server NodeJS is running and in another MySQL.

From NodeJS server, I can check the load average of NodeJS server by `os.loadavg()`.

How can I check the load average of MySQL server from NodeJS server?